# three.js transparency from .png files issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I recently started working in three.js and i am trying to render a human model. i have two objects that are transparent in nature the hair and face and the transparency is taken from a .png image texture. I,m using three.js version r82 and it works perfectly in firefox. But I have an issue with the same code in Google Chrome as the transparent objects act in a bizzare manner.

[image: This is how it works in firefox]

[image: This is how i get in chrome]

im getting the files locally and using THREE.TextureLoader to load the png image files

Kindly help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are all of your materials set to `transparent:true` ?

Comment: There are two transparent objects ...hair and face ..for them transparent is set to true

Comment: add `alphaTest: 0.5` to you material

Comment: That would only make my object have an alphavalue of 0.5 where ever it is transparent...but I want it to get the transparency from the image file ...the same code works perfectly in Firefox ..why only in chrome it has this issue

Comment: Do you apply the texture after it's fully loaded as seen [here](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texturel#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader) ? Have you tried using an older version of Three.js (just in case...) ? Have you tried updating both the material and the texture `material.needsUpdate = true` and `material.map.needsUpdate = true` ?

Comment: I tried using an older version of three.js reverted from 82 to 73 still the issue remains in chrome alone. But this issue is there only if i embed it to another site and run locally. On the other hand if i run it as a separate site it renders properly. Both are local no server attached.

Comment: as for the second yes i have given as new texture and in the onload of the texture loader the material map is assigned and the material is updated. But when i do that i loose the transparency of the object and the object becomes completely opaque.